# Pass an argument to Webpack from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm trying to build both minified and unminified versions of my app (*js* and *css*) using Webpack.
This can be easily done via command-line interface using `-p` or `--optimize-minimize` switch:

```
webpack
webpack -p
```

However, I would like to perform these actions with just one command, so I decided to write a small Node.js script which would run both of these Webpack builds:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var config = require('./webpack.config');
webpack(config, callback); // Build unminified version
```

So the **question** is: can I pass the aforementioned `-p` argument to Webpack from the Node.js script in order to build the minified version? Or maybe there is a simpler way of solving my particular problem?

Of course, I can use [`child_process.exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), but I don't think it's an authentic Node.js way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your default config to webpack an unminified version. Run webpack with that config. Change the configuration from code and run webpack again. Here is a code example.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
//assuming the config looks like this.

var config = {
    entry: "./entry.js",
    output: {
        devtoolLineToLine: true,
        sourceMapFilename: "./bundle.js.map",
        pathinfo: true,
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
        ]
    },
    plugins: []
};

webpack(config).run(); // Build unminified version

config.output.filename = 'bundle.min.js'
config.plugins = [ 
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            include: /\.min\.js$/,
            minimize: true
        })];


webpack(config).run(); // Build minified version
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I ended up using your method and separating the `config` object in order to avoid race condition.

Answer (score 0):

Key `p` is an alias to setting node environment variable `process.env.NODE_ENV="production"` as described [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/bin/config-yargs.js#L270)

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, this is a shortcut for `NODE_ENV` **and** `--optimize-minimize`, and the required minification is done due to the second one.